# How to delete unchecked and insert checked value in database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image: I have table like the below one]

I have to delete the unchecked value and new checked values into a database. How to achieve this? Already existed checkbox also will be posted again. But if they uncheck I need to delete. This is my below code:

```
$already_exist_category = array("68","70")
$newly_posted_category = array("124","125","68") or array("124","125");
```

How to update or delete and insert the newly posted id into the table?

Answer (score 1):

First delete the id which is not there, then insert the data.

```
delete from table where id not in ($already_exist_category)

insert the new id here.
```

Comment: its duplicating the category id

Comment: make sure you check before inserting the values to db you check if the row is already exista.